# Python - how do I put a repeated process in a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this list `['5,4 4,5 8,7', '6,3 3,2 9,6 4,3', '7,6', '9,8', '5,5 7,8 6,5 6,4']` which contains 5 sublists. My goal is to add 1.0 to each number in the list. I think I need to change the format of the list to do this so I split the list into 5 individual sublist.

```
    sublist = Coordinate(line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4])
```

Then I wanted to change the format of the list like this.

```
class Coordinate:
    def __init__(self, list1, list2, list3, list4, list5):
        self.list1 = map(float, list1.replace(',', '.').split())
        self.list2 = map(float, list2.replace(',', '.').split())
        self.list3 = map(float, list3.replace(',', '.').split())
        self.list4 = map(float, list4.replace(',', '.').split())
        self.list5 = map(float, list5.replace(',', '.').split())
```

However doing this 5 times in a row doesn't seem very efficient to me but I do not know how to change this. 
I managed to change list1 to `[6.4, 5.5, 9.7]` by then adding this:

```
self.list1 = [coordinate + 1.0 for coordinate in self.list1]
        return self.list1
```

I still do not know how to make this process efficient without repeating everything. How can I do this?

Comment: maybe create list of lists and then iterate over this list (containing lists 1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python tutorial loop list", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: What is in `list1` et al. in the first place? Seem like you have a string like `'3,14'` and want to convert that to the floating-point value `3.14`. `list1` can't be a list, because `list` doesn't have a `replace` method.

Comment: If you set the locale properly first, you can write `float(locale.delocalize("3,14"))` to get `3.14`.

Comment: This is list1: ```5,4 4,5 8,7```

Comment: You're essentially asking to correct your program, but the cause of code repetition seems to be outside of the code you've actually provided (we don't know how/why/what list1-5 are, do they need to be separately named variables). Please post more of your code

Answer (score 1):

are `list1` until `list5` actually a `list`? because `list` doesn't have method `replace`.

if `list1` until `list5` are string, maybe you can try this one, but you need to make a new `list` containing `list1` until `list5`:

```
lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]
for index, item in enumerate(lists):
    lists[index] = map(float, item.replace(',', '.').split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of your original strings, so that you can easily iterate over their values. I suggest keeping the resulting list of lists when you are done; any time you have a set of names that differ only by some index, that's a sign you should be using a list or a dict instead of separate variable names.

Set the locale to something which uses `,` as a decimal point; if you don't have an obvious one based on where you got the data from in the first place, `sv_SE.UTF-8` should work. This lets you convert strings to floats using `locale.atof` without using the `str.replace` method.

```
import locale

curr_locale = locale.getlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC)
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "sv_SE.UTF-8")
lists = [[locale.atof(x) for x in L.split()] for L in [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5]
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, curr_locale)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like (not recommended but if you have an arbitrary number of lists (say 100):

```
def myfun(l):
    return [a.replace(',', '.').split()) for a in l]


for n in range(1, 100):
    globals()['list{}'.format(n)] = map(myfun, globals()['list{}'.format(n)])
    globals()['list{}'.format(n)] = map(float, globals()['list{}'.format(n)])
```